# Change img src not update the image

Tags: javascript, html

### UPDATE

Finally got why it doesn't work. Server throw an error when I add `timestamp` attribute to `avatar.src`. I have a default no-avatar picture, but for some reason when you set incorrect src it just not updated.

I have the next image:

```
<img id="avatar" src="http://<my_host>/download?userId=1"/>
```

And after update it on the server I unsuccessfully try to update it on client:

```
const avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
// PROBLEM: not update an image
avatar.src = avatar.src + '&timestamp=' + new Date().getTime();
```

BUT:

```
const avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
debugger; // NOW REFRESH WORKS!!
avatar.src = avatar.src + '&timestamp=' + new Date().getTime();
```

**Question:** *how to update the image?*

Comment: sounds like a caching issue. have you checked the response code coming back for the requests for that image. you may have to allow caching whilst using the in-browser debugger so you can observe without affecting it, which I'm guessing it why it works when you call "debugger;"

Comment: Any errors in the console (e.g. `Cannot read property 'src' of null`) ?

Comment: @Andreas no erros, all works correct

Comment: @AntonyScott absolutely right, I switch off caching in debug mode. But how can I bypass caching in this particular case without debugging?

Comment: could it be the server caching settings? I know I've had issues like this in the past where the client won't even request a new image because it was told by the server that it's "valid" for X days

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk that's what the `dateTime` suffix is for... It shouldn't cache..

Comment: @AntonyScott when I open image's url in separate tab and refresh the tab - it update the image

Comment: @AntonyScott after updating the image and requestion it second time I get `Cache-Control:no-cache` from server

Comment: Not really helping, but I want to mention that using `Date.now()` would be slightly faster than constructing a `new Date().getTime()` and is simpler in use.

Comment: This question helps! I didn't knew the trick to force update images because of the cache.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)  will not work in older browsers.

I would have guessed your usage of const fails to store the image object. 
Instead I suggest this:

```
var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
var src = avatar.src;
avatar.src = src + '&timestamp=' + new Date().getTime();
```

It does not make sense to store the image object in a const. Instead you could store the URL in a const:

```
const IMGURL = "http://<my_host>/download?userId=1";
var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
avatar.src = IMGURL + '&timestamp=' + new Date().getTime();
```

**UPDATE:** Since `var` does the same thing in OP's code, I would now look at timing issues. If the setInterval or whatever is used is too fast, adding debugger may slow it down to allow the loading. Hit F12 and see if the network tab shows a lot of interrupted calls

Comment: I use babel, so `const` is absolutely supported

Comment: I missed that. Anyway, it does not make sense to store an image object in a const.

Comment: Also, where do you read that `const` is a 'string representation'? Apart from some browsers not supporting it, most of them do and none of them use string representation according to the article you linked to on MDN. Or am I  missing something here?

Comment: @mplungjan pls forget about `const`, that's only for example purposes. I have absolutelly the same result with `var`

Comment: Can you post the reload code too? It could be you load it too fast and that `debugger` slows it down

Comment: I don't think so to be honest - as far as `const` goes it is functionally equivalent (and as versatile) as `var`, with the only catch that it can't be reassigned, so the use of `const` for an image element is just fine, as long as it is worth that. For example, when using `canvas` to output it might be smart to make the context a constant, meaning no other thing can use that 'variable' name anymore.